# How do you see your html edits after you reload (Firefox DevTools)?

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I feel like this should be really easy to find if it exists, but I've been googling for 10 minutes. [I don't see it mentioned in the official documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#editing_html)

I'm trying to troubleshoot a solution to a problem. The solution requires rearranging the order the `head` child elements.

It's trivial to make that change with Firefox devtools, but I don't know how to view the page with those changes; if I reload (ctrl+r), the HTML goes back to the server version. Does this feature exist?

FWIW, I can find ways of doing this for CSS and JS changes.

Comment: You can write a custom script (_javascript_) to fetch the page from server (e.g using [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)), then alter the HTML as you wish and finally replace the HTML

Comment: @MehdiDehghani i guess at that point, may as well use grease/tamper monkey.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently (as of Firefox 92) no such feature of re-applying HTML changes.

What I found is a [feature request in Mozilla's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1124853).

At the moment, the only workaround for this is to directly transfer the changes on the server side script creating the HTML output once you've done them in the Inspector.

*Note: It requires some heuristics to re-apply changes to HTML in the browser because the resources served over the network could change in the meantime.
For CSS, the simple DevTools solution is to replace a file entirely by the saved one. For JavaScript, they have some heuristics to recognize where a line moved when code has changed between two reloads. Though those solutions cannot be transferred to HTML easily, as it is generated dynamically most of the time.*